# Как написать программу, которая будет показывать максимально отдалённое число от выбранного в списке (таблице)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, таблицы

Есть вот такая таблица в Экселе.

[image: Таблица]

Хочу написать программу на Python, которая будет показывать максимально отдалённое число (значение из таблицы) от выбранного значения в таблице.

С чего начать и что использовать?

Comment: Что есть отдалённое ? Значение или местоподожение ?

Comment: В каком виде у вас эта таблица? пример исходного условия и результата? Что-то вы уже сами написали?

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: @Интик Отдалённое по значению,

Comment: @strawdog есть только таблица в экселе, я пока написал 6 отдельных листов, но мне кажется я в неправильном направлении начал.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas
```

создаем таблицу со случайными данными:

```
In [38]: d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5000, 6000, size=(6,8))).add_prefix("CH")

In [39]: d
Out[39]:
    CH0   CH1   CH2   CH3   CH4   CH5   CH6   CH7
0  5171  5036  5107  5303  5307  5859  5158  5260
1  5574  5928  5217  5706  5056  5138  5637  5513
2  5045  5702  5552  5827  5676  5922  5724  5456
3  5391  5633  5954  5372  5090  5382  5797  5707
4  5603  5476  5710  5736  5562  5108  5197  5749
5  5013  5863  5054  5246  5437  5489  5550  5109
```

находим top 5 ячеек, с мкасимальной разницей по сравнению с ячейкой `2, CH3`:

```
In [41]: (d.stack() - d.at[2, "CH3"]).abs().nlargest(5)
Out[41]:
5  CH0    814
0  CH1    791
2  CH0    782
5  CH2    773
1  CH4    771
dtype: int32
```

---

PS для того, чтобы прочитать данные из Excel файла:

```
d = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

Comment: а пандас для какой версии питона? на 3.8 будет работать?

Comment: @WalterCastillo, будет

Comment: Двоеточие на этой строке ошибку выдаёт Out[39]:

Comment: Я ещё не работал с этим модулем, можно ли это сделать через List?

Comment: @WalterCastillo, конечно можно, но мне лень ;)